# form not returned true or false it take true default

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

my code is :

```
$('#trainer_registration_form_new').submit(function(){
            var email           = $('#email').val();
            var dataString      = 'email='+email;
            $.ajax({
                type     : "get",
                url      : "checkEmail.php",
                data     : dataString,
                async    : false,
                dataType : "html",
                success  : function(result){
                    if(result==1) {
                        alert('email alredy exist');
                        $("input#email").focus();
                        $('#email').val('');
                        tempField =  $('#email');
                        setTimeout("tempField.focus();",1);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                       return true;
                    }
                }
            });
     });
```

what is wrog with this code , i want to just check duplicate email onsubmit from and submit the form. but its not working any other idea ?

Comment: You should share your server code too in order to get a meaningful anser. I guess it is php so you don't need the java tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you intend for your `return false` to prevent the form from submitting? This will not be the case because you are returning `false` from the `success` callback as opposed to the `submit()` callback function.

Instead, you could consider creating a boolean variable at the top of you `submit()` callback and setting it's value within `success` and returning this at the end.

So here's a crude example:

```
$('#trainer_registration_form_new').submit(function(){
   var $form = $(this);
   $.ajax({
      // As you were...
      success: function(result) {
          if(result==1) {
              // As you were..
          } else {
              $form.submit()
     }
   });

   return false;
});
```

Comment: hi juco can you give any example, that whatever you want to say , b'coz i am not understanding u

Comment: @Toms I have updated my answer with a crude example of what I mean

Comment: sorry @juco, it take defalt true, if even ajax will false

Comment: Sorry @Toms I realise that will not work now. I have updated my answer yet again, give that a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is inside the anonymous function passed as the `success` handler of the AJAX request, so will only return a value from that function (to nowhere), not from your submit handler function. You'll need to use a variable to store the return value, and set it to `true` or `false` inside that function instead.

You should ideally avoid using `async: false` as well, since that kind of defeats the entire purpose of using AJAX and will lock up the browser until the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `dataType : "html",` to `dataType : "text",`

`alert(result);` before `if(result==1) {`

Comment: i do that it alert 1 and submit the form